# (Library) checked out status returning all "true"

Tags: java

Instead of using boolean to see if a book was checked out I thought using a string to represent it was what I wanted but when I call the method to checkout a book the string applies to the entire array list of book objects. How can i change the status of just that book ?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Library 
{

  String owner;
  int numBooks;
  boolean isCheckedOut;
  String status = "false";

  ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();



public void addBook(Book b)
{
    bookList.add(b);

}
 public  String checkout(Book c) {

    status = "true";
    return status;

  }

  public Library(String o)
  {
    owner = o;
  }
  public String toString()
  {


   String s = "Owner:    \t" + owner + "\nSize:    \t" + 
               bookList.size()+"\nBooks:   \t";
   for( int i = 0;i < bookList.size();i++)
    { 
      String title = bookList.get(i).getTitle();
      //System.out.println(title);
      s+="\n\t\t\t" +title +"     Checked out: " + status;  //bookList.get(i).getStatus();
    }





    return s;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Library l = new Library("Jeremiah");
    System.out.println(l);



  }
}
```

i

```
public class Mainn
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Book book1  = new Book("Aambi","Aisney","Aalt","1942",1453);
    Book book2  = new Book("Bambi","Bisney","Balt","1942",1453);
    Book book3  = new Book("Cambi","Cisney","Calt","1942",1453);
    Book book4  = new Book("Dambi","Disney","Dalt","1942",1453);
    Book book5  = new Book("Eambi","Eisney","Ealt","1942",1453);
    Book book6  = new Book("Fambi","Fisney","Falt","1942",1453);
    Book book7  = new Book("Gambi","Gisney","Galt","1942",1453);
    Book book8  = new Book("Hambi","Hisney","Halt","1942",1453);
    Book book9  = new Book("Iambi","Iisney","Ialt","1942",1453);
    Book book10 = new Book("Jambi","Jisney","Jalt","1942",1453);
    Book book11 = new Book("Kambi","Kisney","Kalt","1942",1453);
    Library l = new Library("Jeremiah"); 

    // l.addBook(new Book("Xambi","Xisney","Xalt","1579",765)); 

     l.addBook(book1);
     l.addBook(book2);
     l.addBook(book3);
     l.addBook(book4);
     l.addBook(book5);
     l.addBook(book6);
     l.addBook(book7);
     l.addBook(book8);
     l.addBook(book9);
     l.addBook(book10);
     l.addBook(book11);


    // this changes all of the values to true  instead of just this one
     l.checkout(book1);
     l.checkout(book11);

     l.addBook(book1);

      System.out.println(l);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you want to change the status of just that book you need to change the object, book.status = true; and have a field in that object

Comment: You are only setting the status of the entire library. Make sure the book class has a status instance variable and have that updated by your checkout method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the status against the Library, and not against each Book. To check out a single book, you'll need to put the status field into the book, and then set the book's status:

```
public class Book
{
    public String status;
    // etc...
}

public String checkout(Book c) {
    c.status = "true";
    return c.status;
}
```

Storing a boolean value as a string isn't usually the best idea - you'd normally be better off using an actual Boolean field for this.

A cleaner (more object oriented) implementation would look something like:

```
public class Book {

    private boolean checkedOut = false;

    public void checkout() {
        checkedOut = true;
    }

    public void checkin() {
        checkedOut = false;
    }

    public boolean isCheckedOut() {
        return checkedOut;
    }
}
```

This keeps the logic for managing a book with the book itself, and would allow you to easily add validation, such as preventing checkout if the field is already set to true.

Comment: You might unite two methods in one method  changeStatus(), which returned `checkedOut = !checkedOut;`

Comment: Yes, I was going to go with a normal getter/setter implementation, but thought specific checkin()/checkout() methods might make it easier to see how you could extend the class to add validation logic (having a `checkin()` call fail seemed marginally clearer than having a `setStatus()` call fail as an example).

Answer (score 1):

So a big problem I'm seeing here is that you don't have the "Status" attribute on each book separately, you just have the one status String for the entire library.

It's not storing a status for each book.

What you could do is add an attribute called status to the Book class, and in the method where you check it out, you would set that to false. When printing them, you would print the status of each book by accessing this variable within each book object.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the following piece of code help you:

```
public class Book {
    private boolean status;

    public boolean getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

public class Library {
    public  boolean checkout(Book c) {
         c.setStatus(true);
         return c.getStatus(); 
    }
}
```

And I advice to you use a `boolean` primitive type instead a `String` object.